# Get file's Previous Versions, from WINAPI

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, windows-7

In Windows 7 theres a possibility for getting file's previous versions like in the below image:

Is there any way to retrieve file's previous version by code? because I couldn't find any API.

[image]

Thanks advanced! =]

Comment: The magic words are "shadow copies".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some searching, and thanks to @ryyker and @Ben directions I was able to find out the answer:

For example for file: C:\SomeFolder\SomeFile.exe

From cmd (run as administrator):

```
vssadmin list shadows for=C:\
```

For programmatic solution you can run it with:

```
CreateProcessW(NULL,L"cmd.exe /c \"vssadmin list shadows for=C:\\ > C:\\someTmpFile.txt\"",...);
```

Read and parse the created file.

[image]

Here above you get a list of shadow copies (kind of "Previous versions" containers).

Refer to the appropriate "Shadow Copy Volume" row (the version you want) and append the remaining file path after the volume name:

```
\\ Previous version path =  \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy3\SomeFolder\SomeFile.exe"
wchar_t* prevPath = L"\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy3\\SomeFolder\\SomeFile.exe";
```

Now you can read the file with the well known WIN32API functions CreateFile and ReadFile. (Create and Read file example from MSDN: [EXAMPLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Make sure to use the UNICODE versions of that functions as the ASCII version may lack support of "\?\" paths.

Good luck! =]

Answer (score 5):

There are several tags listed with this question.  So it is unclear if a strictly c/c++ approach is desired, or if scripting etc will work.  In any case...

***Here are some links that will hopefully point in the right direction:***

- On the MSDN site, there is documentation and example code referring
  to ***[shadow
  copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***
  API.
- Here is a ***[Link to the
  concept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923636%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)***
  of shadow copy service.
- Here is a description of how you can ***[command line, or program
  script](http://www.greycube.com/site/news.php?item.152)*** to recover
  files from shadow copy.
- Using the API link above with the ***[structures found
  here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***
  will provide you with a way to get information about a particular
  file, volume etc.
- Finally, Here is a link talking about the ***[Volrest utility  from
  Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit
  tools](https://superuser.com/a/644759/141414)***, including
  information on how you can "see a list of available *previous
  versions* of [a] folder".

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @hichris123 - I was editing to find more related links when you down voted.  If I have addressed your concern, please remove the down vote.

Comment: That's not my downvote - so I can't remove it. One thing though: I see you've added more links. *That wasn't my concern*. We'd like to have full answers *here*, so could you please summarize the contents of the links you've given? Also, I'd suggest reading [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/237685).

Comment: @hichris123 - my apologies for the wrong assumption.  Regarding your request to summarize, and _We'd like to have full answers here_:  The question itself, although a valid question, is somewhat vague.   I have presented several options for places to find information, each a different kind, which I believe address OP's concern in the best way possible given the ambiguity of the question.  I would not know how to improve it's form.

Comment: The issue is that the linked api documentation doesn't seem to include any way to query for previous snapshots of a file, or how to access them.

Comment: @IanBoyd - I am not sure what is meant by _previous snapshots_.  Does it mean the same as what Microsoft refers to as _shadow copy_?  Are you referring to the concept of _[versioning](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.basic.in-action.html)_, such as what source control utilities provide for source code files?

Comment: @ryyker **Previous Versions** comes from the name of the tab you find in Windows Explorer (see screenshot in original question). The Previous Versions are sometimes stored in File History, and in **Backups**, and there might also be some stored in **Restore Points** (aka *"Shadow Copies"*?). (Note the **Previous Version Location** in the screenshot: **Backup**, **Restore Point**) The question becomes: how to access what we see in the **Previous Versions** tab in Windows Explorer, but in a *programmatic* way (since we are developers, and this is stackoverflow). I don't see anything in the APIs.