# Restoring previous version in Python

Tags: python, file, corrupt

I am a py script that writes data into excel file. I am running the latter script on VM that sometimes crashes and if at that moment py script was writing data to excel, it corrupts the excel file.

Current solution to fix corrupt files is to manually 'Restore Previous Version' from file properties.
[image]

However I would like to do this task with python. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: and what is the reason you do not plan to fix the script to prevent it from crashing?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski scripts runs fine, it is the Virtual Machine that crashes.

Comment: but why? is it an old version or what happens? did you investigate? I barely seen VM crashing just because...

Comment: Usually it crashes because it runs out of memory. Yes, I know it would be a solution to add more memory to VM or runs less scripts on it, but this is not the case at the moment (I am not able to do it due to corporate nonsense). Thus, I wanted to find temporary solution, in order to save some time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get file's Previous Versions, from WINAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528215/get-files-previous-versions-from-winapi)

Comment: There's no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: @PeterWood what do you mean that there is no python in question? In my post I have asked how to restore file with python.

Comment: @Aertonas Just saying "I want to do this in python" doesn't make it a [tag:python] question.

Comment: @PeterWood I would have posted a code that doesn't work, if I would knew where to start. But I don't know. I came here to as other people to share their knowledge (maybe someone had the same issue and know the approach). If I am wrong, then could you at least write, how should I have presented my problem?

Comment: I've linked to a related question above.

Answer (score 2):

You can save a copy of the excel file before manipulating it. If your script crashes because of an exception then you can catch it and then restore the file. If it crashes because of something like a memory error then you still have the copy of the file as a backup.

Comment: I have many excel files and saving a copy for each would slow the process down. In addition, I have backup copies saved on a server that I can access (by 'Restore Previous Version'), so I wanted to make use of that.

Comment: Then do what I proposed above using the version backed up on the server instead to restore the file.